# select id where one column have a minimum value

Tags: php, mysql

column `cat` is varchar and column `step` is integer
need to select `id` where cat is `lorem` and step is `minimum value`
like this:

```
$sq = "select id from arts where cat = 'lorem' and step = min from step";
```

so if two rows have `cat = lorem` with `step = 2 and 3` - the `id` of the first one should be selected
if another row - not having `cat = lorem` has `step = 1` - it should be ignored
pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$sq = "select id from arts where cat = 'lorem' order by step limit 1"

you can also do order by step desc/asc
Depends on your needs.

Pretty sure that's what you asked for ..